# Finding the generating function for a series based on another generating function

Tags: solution-verification, generating-functions

I was going through Alan Tucker's Applied Combinatorics when I came across this exercise in Chapter 6: Generating Functions, page $281$

> If $h(x)$ is the ordinary generating function for $a_r$, find the generating function for $s_r=\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty a_k$ , assuming all $s_r$'s are finite and $a_r\to 0$ as $r\to \infty$.

We have $h(x)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_rx^r $ and we can define $f(x)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty s_rx^r$ to be the generating function we wish to identify. Thus,

$$f(x)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty a_k\right)x^r=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \left(h(1)-\sum_{k=0}^r a_k\right)x^r$$

Expanding,
$$f(x)=h(1)\sum_{r=0}^\infty x^r -\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^r a_k\right)x^r=\frac{h(1)}{1-x}-\frac{h(x)}{1-x}=\frac{h(1)-h(x)}{1-x}$$

Could someone please check if I'm right? Or offer another solution if I'm wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I checked it, seems to be true.

Comment: @on1921379 Thank you for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.  Another approach is to interchange the order of summation:
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty a_k\right) x^r
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} x^r \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \frac{1-x^k}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k - \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{(h(1) - a_0) - (h(x) - a_0)}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{h(1) - h(x)}{1-x}
\end{align}

Comment: I quite like this answer. Thank you!